# Add book, chapter, or both to Google Scholar profile?

Tags: google-scholar

I'm co-author of a chapter of a book, and both the chapter and the book have Google Scholar entries. My question is whether I should add just the chapter, or just the book, or both to my Google Scholar account.

I'm thinking almost certainly not both, since you don't put both on a CV, but I'm really just not sure what Google Scholar etiquette is in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would add the chapter, because that's what you authored.

If you also edited the book while authoring/co-authoring a chapter, I'd add both.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense — especially the “if I helped edit, then add both” :)